# Can we display a HTML element at the end of the DOM somewhere further up the DOM instead?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible to display an HTML element somewhere at the end of the DOM somewhere further up the DOM instead (using CSS).

The element should still be placed with `position:relative`!

I created a "possible solution" with flexbox below to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, but

- (a) it's not done with `position:relative`
- (b) the caveat I see here is that it only works if the  `order` property is assigned to every HTML element that is subject to `display: flex`. In reality, if I'd want to move an element from right before `</body>` to right after `<body>` I wouldn't want to assign `order` to every single element in the DOM.

I'm interested in a solution with `position:relative`, because I have to deal with an existing CSS setup based on this positioning paradigm.

```css
.content {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
 }

.content-piece {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 1px;
 }
 
 #bot {
  order: 1;
 }
 
 #top {
  order: 2;
 }
 
 #mid {
  order: 3;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Move bot to the top of body</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Goal: Make Bottom display above Top</p>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-piece" id="top">Top</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="mid">Middle</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="bot">Bottom</div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would say there are three ways to do it. Nr. 1 like you did with "flex" or Nr. 2 "grid" or Nr. 3 manipulating the DOM with javascript. So with css only 2 ways that i know :)

Comment: If you use flex or grid , you should have a few option without position, but or order and/or grid-area/grid-row/grid-column. there is also the trick to rearrange the visual flow mixing float and non float element where some can be cleared and others not, but alike position, it is not the way to go unless you are looking for funny behaviors ;) .

Comment: Are you saying that this *must* be done with `position: relative`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, that is what I'm trying to achieve. The flex solution, although arguably not the neatest possible way I set it up, was more to go from "this is how you probably should do it" to "this is how you can do it given the restraint of position:relative"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaut `order` is **zero `0`**, to bring one at front, use **`-1`** ;)

demo

```css
.content {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
 }

.content-piece {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 1px;
 }
 
 #bot {
  order: -1;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Move bot to the top of body</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Goal: Make Bottom display above Top</p>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-piece" id="top">Top</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="mid">Middle</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="bot">Bottom</div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

or set the **others** to **`1`**

```css
.content {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
 }

.content-piece {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 1px;
 }
 
 .content [id]:not(#bot) {
  order: 1;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Move bot to the top of body</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Goal: Make Bottom display above Top</p>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-piece" id="top">Top</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="mid">Middle</div>
      <div class="content-piece" id="bot">Bottom</div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no need to reset order for each in your case.

---

**For the fun** and **not** with `position:relative` (nor `translate()`) , here is a float behavior that could be used before `flex` or `grid` shown up.

```css
.content-piece {
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.content::before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 60px; /* equals height of #bot , can be retrieve via js and injected */
  float: left;
}

#bot {
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* no float !! */
}

#top {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  /* set it below the pseudo */
}

#mid {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  /* if not wide enough to be  to pushed below previous float  */
}
```

```html
<p>Goal: Make Bottom display above Top</p>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-piece" id="top">Top</div>
  <div class="content-piece" id="mid">Middle</div>
  <div class="content-piece" id="bot">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

or if you really want `position:relative`, mix it with `position sticky` in a funny tricky use again not to use in real :

```css
.content-piece {
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
 .content {position:relative;border:solid;overflow:auto;}

#bot {
position:sticky; 
bottom:1500px;/* whatever is enough to push it up */
height:60px;
}
#top {
margin-top:60px;
}
```

```html
<p>Goal: Make Bottom display above Top</p>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-piece" id="top">Top</div>
  <div class="content-piece" id="mid">Middle</div>
  <div class="content-piece" id="bot">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

**`Flex` is really not bad here ;).**

Comment: I realise the code can be neater and it is useful to point this out. Thanks!
My actual question is about achieving this with the position property set to 'relative' though.

Comment: @SomewhereDave `position:relative`? you need to know the size of each elements and their position *(top is easy it's average at top:0;)* to swap them around , and then  avoid then to overflow on top another or leave a gap. You can have fun trying, but do not use it live ;) You can use javascript to retrieve position and size and calculate new offset position for each.